# Converting navigation menu tabs from radio and label tags to UL and LI navigation

Tags: css

I found this navigation tab style that I really like...but I am not a css guru.
https://codepen.io/markcaron/pen/MvGRYV

[css tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f30MX.png)

It uses radio and label tags and I am having a challenging time converting it to something I am more familiar with seeing in the structure of ul and li tags. I want the links to go to a web page and not toggling to contents within the same page.

- Some Thing
- Some Thing 2
- Some Thing 3
- Some Thing 4

```
Any guidance or help is much appreciated.
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried already. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.

Comment: Not doable with pure CSS. This hack is used to give a tab an active (:checked) state to address it in CSS. IF you want to sue the semantic correct `menu` and `li` then you need JavaScript to apply an active state

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. Do not just send us to external platforms to see what code you are talking about in the first place..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technique is quite simple: Every `<li>` needs to have a `border-bottom`. When you select that `<li>`, you add the `border` to all 4 directions and remove the `border-bottom`:

```js
// JS is only needed when be used on the same site, otherwise hardcode the class to the correct li
let list_items = document.querySelectorAll('menu li');
list_items.forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    list_items.forEach(list => list.classList.remove('active'));
    e.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
  })
)
```

```css
menu {
  padding-left: 0;
  display: flex;
}

menu > li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1em;
}

menu > li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* class that needs to be added to the li that is active / checked / selected */
.active {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: none;
}


/* only for demonstration purpose */
a {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <menu>
    <li class="active"><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
  </menu>
</nav>
```